# Recursing Through Nested List LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How would I recurse through nested lists?

For example, given: `'((A 1 2) (B 3 4))`

How would I add 2 to the second element in each nested sublist?

```
(defun get-p0 (points)
    (loop for x from 0 to
            (-  (list-length    points) 1) do
                (+ 2 (cadr (nth x points)))
    )
)
```

I'm not really sure why `(get-p0 '((A 1 2) (B 3 4)))` returns NIL.

Comment: Please invest a few minutes to learn [how to format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
(loop for (letter x y) in '((A 1 2) (B 3 4))
     collect (list letter (+ 2 x) y))
```

The reason: it's shorter and you don't measure the length of the list in order to iterate over it (why would you do that?)

Comment: What if I wanted to operate on values from both lists in the same function? For instance, I wanted to add x1 to x2?

Comment: x1 would be 1 and x2 would be 3.

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask for a recursive solution:

```
(defun get-p0 (lst &optional (n 0))
  (if (null lst) 
      nil
      (let ((elt1 (first lst)) (eltn (cdr lst)))
        (if (listp elt1)
             (cons (get-p0 elt1) (get-p0 eltn))
             (cons (if (= n 1) (+ elt1 2) elt1) (get-p0 eltn (+ n 1)))))))
```

so

```
? (get-p0 '((A 1 2) (B 3 4)))
((A 3 2) (B 5 4))
```

and it recurses further down if necessary:

```
? (get-p0 '((A 0 2) ((B -4 4) (C 10 4))))
((A 2 2) ((B -2 4) (C 12 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, you can consider the problem as a basic recursion pattern: you go through a list using recursion or iteration (`mapcar`, `reduce`, etc.; `dolist`, `loop`, etc.) and apply a function to its entries. Here is a functional solution:

```
(defun get-p0 (points)
  (mapcar #'add-2 points))
```

where the auxiliary function can be defined as follows:

```
(defun add-2 (lst)
  "Add 2 to the 2nd item"
  (let ((res '()))
    (do ((l lst (cdr l))
         (i 1 (1+ i)))
      ((null l) (nreverse res))
      (push (if (= 2 i)
              (+ 2 (car l))
              (car l))
            res))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As written your 'loop' use does not return anything; thus NIL is returned.  As is your code is simply iterating over x and computing something; that something isn't stored anywhere.

So, how to get your desired result?  Assuming you are willing to modify each point in points, this should work:

```
(defun get-p0 (points)
  (loop for x from 0 to (- (list-length points) 1) do
    (let ((point (nth x points)))
      (setf (cadr point) (+ 2 (cadr point)))))
   points)
```

Comment: Just note that this is a destructive operation since it modifies the initial list.

Comment: Yes, I noted that in the answer.