# List of Lists trouble LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to LISP so I'm not very good at this... So my problem is, I've been given a structure (list of lists) and my job is to create a function that retrives the second item in each sub list (counting from 0). So in the end I would like to return (fruit fruit agent yard).

I can do the basic recursion calls that goes through the lists but I can't seem to figure out how to get the second item in the sub list.

Structure of the lists:

```
(defparameter *jack*
'((orange#8 apple fruit basment)
(pear#12 mango fruit basment)
(jones rabbit agent closet)
(jack dog agent yard)
))
```

Code I have so far:

```
(defun attempt(*data*)
(cond ((null *data*)
     nil
     )
    ((attempt (rest *data*)))
    ))
```

What I'm thinking is that I should be iterating through the list sub lists using first and rest but like I said, I can't figure it out. Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return the second element for every element in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599562/return-the-second-element-for-every-element-in-a-list)

Comment: Oops, that "possible duplicate" is in Scheme, but this is Common Lisp.  The answer still works, but you have to use `mapcar` instead of `map`, and you should use `'second` instead of `cadr`.  (You could also use `'cadr` or `#'cadr`, but `'second` more clearly states the intent, in my opinion.)

Comment: For another example of `mapcar`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15351988/1281433.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'caddr *jack*)
(FRUIT FRUIT AGENT AGENT)
```

EDIT: If you want to practise your recursive approach, try:

```
(defun attempt (list-of-lists)
    (if (null list-of-lists) nil
        (cons (third (car list-of-lists))
              (attempt (cdr list-of-lists)))))
```

EDIT2: Tail-recursively:

```
(defun attempt-tail (list-of-lists)
    (labels ((iter (rest ans)
               (if (null rest) (nreverse ans)
                   (iter (cdr rest) (push (third (car rest)) ans)))))
      (iter list-of-lists nil)))
```

EDIT3: While I'm at it, here's the loop version:

```
(loop for list in *jack* collect (third list))
```

Comment: First of all thanks! And secondly, I was wondering if you it was possile to answer this question using tail recursion?

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably what you are looking for:

```
(mapcar #'cadr *jack*)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can define for this process you want a tail-recursive procedure;

```
(defun nths (n l)"returns list of nths of a list of lists l"
  (nths-aux n l '()))

(defun nths-aux (n l A)
  (if (null l) A;or (reverse A)
   (nths-aux n (cdr l)  (cons (nth n (car l)) A))))
```

Comment: BTW have you heard of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailrecursion-modulo-cons?sort=newest&pageSize=50 ?

Comment: No i haven't, but it seems interesting, maybe i look up it sometime.